# Python - Can't figure Out Why Regex Does and Doesn't Work In These Codes?

Tags: python, regex

I am a newbie to python, and I have started to learn some Regex. I have been trying to get a match for some text in a string, and have bumped into something I don't understand. Here is my code:

```
import re

pattern1 = r'\b\w+\b,\s\b\w+\b'
pattern2 = r'\b\w+\b,\s\b\w+\b,'

# pattern1 produces expected result
with open('test_sentence.txt', 'r') as input_f:
    for line in input_f:
        word = re.search(pattern1, line)
        print word.group()

# pattern 2, same as pattern1 but with additional ',' at the end
# does not work.
with open('test_sentence.txt', 'r') as input_f:
    for line in input_f:
        word = re.search(pattern2, line)
        print word.group()
```

Here is the content of the test_sentence.txt:

```
I need to buy are bacon, cheese and eggs. 
I also need to buy milk, cheese, and bacon.
What's your favorite: milk, cheese or eggs.
What's my favorite: milk, bacon, or eggs.
```

I cannot understand why `pattern2` won't work It throws a `none-type object has no attribute group` error in reference to `print word.group()`. I believe this means it could not find a match for the regex code of 'pattern2'. Why is the extra `,` at the end causing this issue? Why does it not simply match `milk, cheese,' and` milk, bacon,`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are searching in each line and not the whole file. This means that there are multiple lines in which pattern2 will not match and which will return `None` which causes the error. Move the second line to the top and you will see that this line matches and the error occurs later at the second line.

Always check the return value before using it:

```
word = re.search(pattern2, line)

if word:
    print word.group()
else:
    print "No match"
```

Comment: thanks! It was driving me a bit nutty, so I figured I would have to ask at SO :-) I didn't realize it was matching on a per line basis, so now you made that clear to me, I used the `.read()' function on the text file and that solved the issue. Cheers.